# Test whether a function ever descends at $80^\circ$ or more

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives, graphing-functions

I'm designing a roller coaster and the constraint is that it can't go down at a higher angle than  $80^\circ$.  I tried using integrals, but the problem is that I have to manually set the bounds. Anything that can help? double integrals or something?

Basically
$$f '(x)>\tan\left(\dfrac{5\pi}{9}\right)$$

(it will be a piece-wise function)

Comment: Well, you said it yourself: your constraint is $f'(x)<\tan80^\circ$, no integrals needed.

Comment: Looks to me that you have formulated the condition correctly. Now you only have to plug in $f$ and check if the condition holds for all $x$. We don't know what the function is, so there's nothing we can do right now.